# The method is undefined for the type in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, undefined

Method is undefined for the type in Eclipse. Can't seem to solve it. The error is in the lines:             msg.setTimestamp( System.currentTimeMillis() ); and             msg.setBody("this is a test SMS message");

```
package com.example.smsnotification;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class PopSMSActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Retrieve serializable sms message object by the key "msg" used to pass to it
        Intent in = this.getIntent();
        PopMessage msg = (PopMessage) in.getSerializableExtra("msg");

        //Case where we launch the app to test the UI EG: No incoming SMS
        if(msg==null){
            msg = new PopMessage();
            con.setPhone("0123456789");
            msg.setTimestamp( System.currentTimeMillis() );
            msg.setBody("this is a test SMS message");
        }
        showDialog(msg);
    }
```

Comment: please post your stackTrace

Comment: @ankit there is no stacktrace and it wouldn't tell you anything. Please read more careful before posting such comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the code and write it back to eclipse. It worked for me....You can try copy and paste to after writing signature of function/class.

Comment: Also try restarting Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

This means the `PopMessage` class doesn't provide the methods `setTimestamp(long)` and `setBody(String)`.

There is no `import` statement for `PopMessage` in your code so I assume it is a class which you have implemented and is contained in the same package as the `Activity` which you have posted.

So you could either solve this by implementing those two methods in `PopMessage` or by removing the calls.

Answer (score 2):

You may also extend your Eclipse Settings by activating the "save Actions" (Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions) and use the Option "Organize Imports". This would at least add the propbably missing Import "...PopMessage" while you press Ctrl+S.